# next.js API routes share database

Tags: next.js, sequelize.js

I want to use next.js routes api as a backend service and serve database result in json format. I see, there is no way to keep database up and running since all files located at `pages/api/` it's ephemeral

Below it's my code

```
import { models } from "../models/index"

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const User = models.User
  
  try {
    const result = await User.findAll()
    
    return res.json({ result })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error occured ", err)
    return res.json({ result: [] })
  }
}
```

anyone who has encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way that I found is to use node js server and attach database model to `request` object. By doing this we pass database conection/models through routes api

my node.js server

```
const express = require("express")
const { sequelize } = require("./models/index")
const next = require("next")
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
const appExpress = express()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  appExpress.use(express.json())

  appExpress.get("*", (req, res) => {
    req.db = sequelize
    handle(req, res)
  })

  
  appExpress.listen(5000, () => console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:5000"))
}).catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

my routes api file changed to

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const User = req.db.models.User
  
  try {
    const result = await User.findAll()
    
    return res.json({ result })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error occured ", err)
    return res.json({ result: [] })
  }
}
```

with these changes the database is always up and running and used from all routes api files.
I tested and work like charm